# Feasibly of a Neptune-like planet in the habitable zone

Tags: space, gas-giants

Is it possible for a Neptune-like exoplanet, that is initially positioned beyond the frost zone of its star system, to undergo a migration process that relocates it to the habitable zone?

Additionally, could this hypothetical migration lead to conditions favorable for one of the moons of this plane to sustain liquid water on its surface and potentially support life?

Comment: There do exist hot Jupiters AKA gas giants  surprisingly close to their star. So warm Neptune is plausible  That is "hot Jupiter" is a useful search term.

Comment: imagine you are play tug-of-war with a friend and to win you must exert more force than your friend does, in this case you are looking at a cataclysmic event

Answer (score 1):

**It's not *impossible*, but *very improbable*.**

You're talking about moving a gas giant-sized planet. Moving it closer to its star to bring it out of the frost zone can be done by repeated and very coordinated gravity assists, perhaps by large asteroids or even moons or small planetoids. Hurling smaller celestial bodies near your quasi-Neptune could gradually change its orbit, eventually moving it into the habitable zone. Of course, they'd need to be thrown fast as not to get trapped as a moon of the gas giant.

For this to happen naturally, one of two things would have to happen:

1. Many smaller celestial bodies would have to enter the solar system at high speed, passing near the gas giant but not colliding with it, in just the right way for the orbit to be reduced repeatedly; or
2. One *really big* planet or high-speed brown dwarf comes in on a parabolic trajectory around the gas giant's host star, pulling the gas giant all the way through the habitable zone (and probably a bit too close for comfort for a little bit) on its way in and, passing past the gas giant again, fixing its orbit in the perfect way so that the gas giant stays in the habitable zone.

The probability of either of these things happening naturally are unbelievably low, but certainly not zero.

**Or, maybe it wasn't so natural after all**. A K-1 civilization long since extinct, some sort of ion engine that uses the gas giant's atmosphere as fuel ... Perhaps what happened is, as the star went through its life cycle, the previous civilization realized that their originally-habitable gas giant was going to fall into the frost zone, and built a giant engine to shift its orbit into the new habitable zone. Then they simply disappeared, either by self-extinction or leaving their home planet for some other. Beyond moving the gas giant into the habitable zone, it's up to you.

Comment: Such planets are well known, actually. Check out [Hot Jupiters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Jupiter) -- gas giants *very close* to their stars.

Comment: @elemtilas The question specifically asks for a Neptune-like exoplanet *initially positioned beyond the frost zone* moved into the habitable zone somehow; a Hot Jupiter would be elsewhere to begin with.

Comment: Check out the [Grand Track Model](https://astrobiology.nasa.gov/news/jupiters-grand-tack-reshaped-the-solar-system/). This posits that Jupiter formed, moved in closer to the Sun, then moved out again. Which either means we're seeing a similar window in time for these planets, before they migrate outwards again; or we're seeing gas planets in stable orbits around stars.

Comment: Good point; I note that this process supposedly has taken billions of years. That's a valid process by which this could happen but I assumed (possibly wrongly) that the timescale that @asteroidbelt was looking for was something closer to thousands or millions of years instead of billions. Should I receive more information I'll update my answer.

Comment: Actually, according to at least some [Grand Track information](https://societyofmodernastronomy.wordpress.com/2015/01/04/the-secret-power-of-resonances/) I've found, the whole movement takes only a few hundred million years! In any event, 70k to 100k years to shift a planet from outer to inner star system!

Comment: I think there's a mismatch over what initial means.  Early solar system formation is now known to be chaotic so basically a planet can end up anywhere in theory regardless of where it starts and there are plenty of examples both real and modeled.  Now if we're talking about moving something in a stable orbit - yeah that takes some effort.